# Covered patio junction box requirements

Tags: junction-box, patio

I'm in Florida and completing a covered patio project that extends my current roof over the patio. The ceiling height is 9'. I'm looking to extend the existing outdoor circuit that is GFCI protected and PVC 1/2" encased. The patio ceiling is drywall (green board) and roof is peel&stick with 3 tab shingle. I need a junction box to economically complete the 3 outlets I want to add. My question is if the junction box is recessed into the patio ceiling (not covered it would be accessable but painted to color match)  does it need to be a weatherproof junction box or can I attach a standard metal box (ground bond required) that you would typically see in an indoor implementation? If weatherproof is required, I have a 4 hole requirement on the back side, does anyone have a product suggestion?

Comment: A) What does "roof is peel & stick" mean? B) They make metal weatherproof boxes. C) Product recommendations are explicitly off-topic, though suggestions are often made in answers.

Comment: I think if you look at code, the issue will be is the box in a "dry" or "damp/moist" or "wet" location. They've got definitions, but the inspector's judgement will rule.

Comment: Found this which says you need a weatherproof receptacle: 
(A) Damp Locations
A receptacle installed outdoors in a location protected from the weather or in other damp locations shall have an enclosure for the receptacle that is weatherproof when the receptacle is covered.
A receptacle shall be considered to be in a location protected from the weather where located under roofed open porches, canopies, marquees, and the like, and will not be subjected to a beating rain or water runoff. All 15- and 20-ampere, 125-and 250-volt nonlocking receptacles shall be a listed weather-resistant type.

Comment: From Mike Holt's forum: Boxes with KO's are permitted in dry and damp locations when they're installed to keep water out of them. Wet locations have a different requirement.
    Part II. Installation
    314.15 Damp or Wet Locations. In damp or wet locations, boxes, conduit bodies and fittings shall be
    placed or equipped so as to prevent moisture from entering or accumulating within the box, conduit bodies or fitting. ... Approved
    drainage openings ...  shall be permitted to be
    installed in the field in boxes or conduit bodies listed for use in damp or wet locations.